# How do I hide the navigation menu in Plone on the home page

Tags: plone

I'd like to remove the navigation portlet just when someone is viewing the home page.  Is this possible?  I'm using Plone 2.5.3, Zope 2.9.8.  Would I need to upgrade to a newer Plone to do that?  I've tried to go to Plone 3 and 4 but I couldn't get the site to start with the old data.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter the ZMI and edit the properties tab of your Plone site. If you like to have the navigation portlet in any folder, enter the folder via ZMI and add a lines property "left_slot". Set the value as in the level of your Plone site.

This advice is only for an old Plone like yours. Newer Plones are managed by the portlet manager.

Comment: Ok, I removed the entries from the left_slot at the root of Plone and the navigation went away for the whole site.  What do I need to put in the new "left_slot" property for the folders where I do want the navigation?  I put in the two entries that were in the "left_slot" at the root: `here/portlet_navigation/macros/portlet
here/portlet_related/macros/portlet` but it's not coming up.  I'm thinking it's a path issue but I don't know what to replace `here` with.

Comment: Isn't the name of the property "left_slots"? (Plural)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to target a specific page easily enough by simply hiding it with css. Plone applies a body css class to every page with the id of the top level item.

For instance, if you have a object "front-page" that is your default view for the home page, you could remove the navigation by using a css rule like:

```
.section-front-page div#[navigation-id]{ display:none;}
```

Not sure if Plone 2.5 allows you to block parent portlets in specific contexts--that's the best way to do it and the way it's done with later versions of plone.